# How to obtain the gradient of the categorical_cross_entropy on Keras using Tensorflow backend?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, loss-function

I'm trying to obtain the gradient of the loss objective, in my case `categorical_cross_entropy` w.r.t to NN parameters such as 'weights' and 'bias'.

The reason for this is I want to implement a callback function with the above as the base, with which I could debug the model while it's training.

So, here's the problem.

I'm currently using generator methods to fit, evaluate and predict on the dataset.

The `categorical_cross_entropy` loss function in Keras is implemented as follows:

```
def categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
```

The only way I can get my hands on `y_pred` is if I evaluate/predict at the end of training my model.

So, what I'm asking is the following:

- Is there a way for me to create a callback as mentioned above?
- If anyone already has implemented a callback like the one above using `categorical_cross_entropy`, please let me know how to make it work?
- Lastly, how to compute the numeric gradient for the same?

Currently, this is the code I'm using to calculate the gradient. But, I've no clue if this is right/wrong. [Link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694344/calculating-gradient-norm-wrt-weights-with-keras)

```
def symbolic_gradients(model, input, output):
    grads = K.gradients(model.total_loss, model.trainable_weights)
    inputs = model.model._feed_inputs + model.model._feed_targets + 
    model.model._feed_sample_weights
    fn = K.function(inputs, grads)

    return fn([input, output, np.ones(len(output))])
```

Ideally I'd like to make this model-agnostic, but even if it's not, it's okay.

Answer (score 0):

I can help with gradient part. I am using this function to calculate gradient of the loss function w.r.t output.

```
def get_loss_grad(model, inputs, outputs):
    x, y, sample_weight = model._standardize_user_data(inputs, outputs)
    grad_ce = K.gradients(model.total_loss, model.output)
    func = K.function((model._feed_inputs + model._feed_targets + model._feed_sample_weights), grad_ce)
    return func(x + y + sample_weight)
```