# Keras, calculating gradients of the loss wrt the input on an LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gradient

I am quite new to machine learning and I was messing around with adversarial-examples.
I am trying to fool a binary character-level LSTM text classifier.
Thus I need the gradient of the loss w.r.t. the input.

The gradients function although returns `None`.

I already tried to get the gradients, like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49312989/keras-calculating-derivatives-of-model-output-wrt-input-returns-none)
or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694344/calculating-gradient-norm-wrt-weights-with-keras), but the gradients function still returns `None`.

EDIT: I wanted to do something similar than in [this](https://github.com/soumyac1999/FGSM-Keras) git repo.

I was thinking that the problem might be that it was an LSTM classifier.
I am not sure at this point. But I think that it should be possible to get these gradients even from an LSTM classifier right?

Here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.models import load_model
import data
import pickle
import keras.backend as K

def adversary():
    model, valid_chars = loadModel()    
    model.summary()

    #load data
    X, y, maxlen, _ , max_features, indata = prepare_data(valid_chars)

    target = y[0]

    # Get the loss and gradient of the loss wrt the inputs  
    target = np.asarray(target).astype('float32').reshape((-1,1))
    loss = K.binary_crossentropy(target, model.output)
    print(target)
    print(model.output)
    print(model.input)
    print(loss)
    grads = K.gradients(loss, model.input)

    #f = K.function([model.input], [loss, grads])

    #print(f(X[1:2]))
    print(model.predict(X[0:1]))

    print(grads)
```

The output looks like this:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 74, 128)           5120      
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 128)               131584    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 129       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 1)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 136,833
Trainable params: 136,833
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Maxlen: 74
Data preparing finished
[[0.]]
Tensor("activation_1/Sigmoid:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
Tensor("embedding_1_input:0", shape=(?, 74), dtype=float32)
Tensor("logistic_loss_1:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
[[1.1397913e-13]]
[None]
```

I was hoping to get the gradients of the loss w.r.t. the input data to see which of the characters has the most impact on the output.
Thus I could fool the classifier by modifying the respective characters.
Is this possible? If yes, what is wrong with my approach?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found [this thread](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12270).
The gradients function returns `None` because the embedding layer in not differentiable.

> The embedding layer is implemented as K.gather which is not differentiable, so there is no gradient.

Answer (score 1):

Gradients can only be computed for "trainable" tensors, so you might want to wrap your input into tf.Variable().

As soon as you want to work with gradient, I would suggest doing it using tensorflow, which nicely integrates with Keras. Below is my example of doing it, note that it works in eager execution mode (default in tensorflow 2.0).

```
def train_actor(self, sars):
    obs1, actions, rewards, obs2 = sars


    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        would_do_actions = self.compute_actions(obs1)
        score = tf.reduce_mean(self.critic(observations=obs1, actions=would_do_actions))
        loss = - score

    grads = tape.gradient(loss, self.actor.trainable_weights)
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.actor.trainable_weights))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not very familiar with tensorflow though.
I unfortunately cannot see how I can integrate your provided code into my program.
Could you provide me a good resource where I could read up on that topic?

Comment: Official documentation is a good start: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients, https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer